# Hard drive issues

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I have a secondary hard drive, 2TB western digital caviar, that has been giving me issues lately. The drive will occasionally have corrupt data on it and programs will be unable to write to it. This fixes itself with a scan and repair through Windows, but it has been happening more often, almost every day this week. It's a relatively new drive, less than 3 years old. I'm running windows 8 64 bit.

UPDATE: The tool from WD couldn't fully evaluate my drive. It said that there are too many bad sectors. Guess I'll have to check with WD support to see what can be done about it. Right now I'm backing up what data I can fit on my primary drive. The rest I'll just have to replace later.

Another update: The drive is going to be replaced by WD free of charge. I lost a lot of games and music, but I can get it back once I get the space.

Answer (score 2):

I've had such a drive that was acting up.  After it eventually failed, I had to replace it.  That drive was under a year old!

So my suggestion to you is...ACT NOW to save any important information off the drive.  Make sure your backups are up-to-date.  Replace the drive ASAP if you want to continue to use your machine without fear of data corruption!

Comment: I have no backup options available to me, apart from my tiny primary drive.

Comment: You can't copy your important stuff to a USB device?

Comment: I can, but most of my important irreplaceable stuff is on my primary drive already. The stuff on my secondary drive is mostly games from Steam and stuff that would take weeks to replace because my internet is so crappy.

Comment: USB drives are relatively inexpensive are even available from Costco come in sizes up to 4TB.

Comment: I'm limited to what I can get from Amazon or Tiger Direct because of where I live. And USB drives that size are not in my budget right now.

Answer (score 1):

Immidiately use a tool to see the SMART attributes of the Hard Drive. A tool like this is CrystalDiskInfo and you can downlaod it here  http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html . This will also report the bad attributes of the hard drive. If you hard drive has bad SMART attributes do a backup ASAP and stop using the drive (especially write).

Comment: This makes me sad. I've been on a tight budget lately and I have absolutely no backup options, aside from my 500gb primary drive. If I have to format the drive, I will have to start over from scratch. :( I am getting that program now though. Will report in a minute.

Comment: Okay, got the program. The health status shows caution. Reallocated Sectors Count is currently 197, Current Pending Sector Count and Uncorrectable Sector Count are both 198. I have to admit this is kind of greek to me.

Comment: @jaxxis Seems that the hard drive is failing and it's only a matter of time before it completely becomes useless. How old is the hard drive and have you ever hit it or something?

Comment: Less than 3 years, and no.

Comment: Good news. The drive is still in limited warranty. ._. Guess I'll try getting it fixed from WD or see if it can be replaced.

Comment: I don't think WD will fix your drive, it will propably replace it so before handing the HDD back take a backup of what you can ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens again, concerning the sectors I recommend booted into a copy of [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) and then doing a quick erase to zero out the sectors. If you ever hear any beeps or a crackle check your computer, that usually means the hard drive is about to go. If your looking for a better one take a look at a [Seagate Barracuda](http://pcpartpicker.com/part/seagate-internal-hard-drive-st2000dm001).